# Is it possible to synchronize 2 bare repos in GIT?

Tags: git

In my project , I'm asked to set-up to 2 GIT repositories(identical) at two locations , say location A and location B and at both the locations check-ins will be done actively.
My requirement is 2 sync both the repo contents along with its branches every day.
Its like A -->B and B-->A . Is it possible or will I run into any merge issues during this, if its possible,how so ?

Assuming my repo name is - "myrepo" in both of the locations

Thanks in advance, Cheers!!

Comment: Are both actively maintained?

Comment: @ Ionică Bizău : yes, both are actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can synchronize two bare repos.  But you will not be able to merge, because merging requires a working copy to resolve conflicts.  The easiest way to merge is to use a third repo which is not bare.

Comment: Could you pls. let me know how can I synchronize two bare repos?

Comment: Um... same way you sync other kinds of repos?  You just can't `git pull` or `git merge`, but you can still `git fetch` and `git push`.